# Go to definition for .jsx does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code, reactjs

I am working with es6 syntax in Visual Studio Code and when I import ordinary file, then I can click F12 (Go to definition) and it works just fine. The problem is that with components (import from .jsx files) it does not work at all (nothing happens when you click `go to definition`). Has anyone an idea how it can be fixed?

P.S. I have `jsconfig.json` like that to allow proper go to definition for ordinary .js files:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This should work but there were some bugs in VSCode 1.13 around `go to definition` on jsx components. Try out the [current insiders builds](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders) to see if these have been fixed. If you still see this issue in the insiders builds,  please open an issue against VSCode and I'll take a look: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new

Comment: I have tried, it seems it does not work either. Will try to create an issue when I remember my password to github :)

Comment: Hi! I have created an issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30290

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although you can track down the solution from [github issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30290) mentioned in one of the comments, I wanted to make it easier for SO users. Quote from the Github issues page:

> easy workaround is to add the compilerOption "jsx": "preserve" (or
>   "jsx": "react" or "jsx": "react-native")

jsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

Comment: You can create `jsconfig.json` in the root directory of your Javascript project.

Comment: if "jsx": "react" not work then check you're paths are correctly mapped or not.